# Javascript code in custom link

Tags: javascript, url, custom-link

I am using Javascript code in Custom link to open a URL or display Error message based on the condition.

Behavior= Execute Javascript
Content Source= Onclick javascript

```
if('{object__c.field1__c}' <> 'Z0' || '{object__c.field1__c}' <> 'Z4')
{
window.alert("Error Message");
}
else
{
window.open("https://xxxx.net/parmeter1={!object__c.field2}&parameter2= 
{!object__c.field3}");
}
```

But, It is not working. Can anyone give suggestion please.

The following error is coming when I click on the custom link:

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I am getting error. I have added in question. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does **not** use `<>` to mean "not equals." Instead, you could use `!=`, or you can even just use a formula. Also, make sure your merge fields are also in the `{! ... }` format. You're also confusing `||` with `&&`. With `||`, if `field1__c` is Z0, then it will not be Z4; in other words, it would always evaluate to true! Here's a modified version of your code:

```
// Using merge formula!
if({!Object__c.Field1__c<>'Z0'&&Object__c.Field1__c<>'Z4'}) {
  alert('Error Message');
} else {
  window.open("https://xxxx.net/parmeter1={!object__c.field2}&parameter2={!object__c.field3}");
}
```

If you were not using a merge formula, it'd look like this:

```
if('{!Object__c.Field1__c}'!='Z0'&&'{!Object__c.Field1__c}'!='Z4') {
```

Note that this method is definitely *not* recommended; it's way too easy to make mistakes, and is definitely less readable than a simple formula.